# SharePoint 2010 Find if User is in one of any listed group Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, security, sharepoint-2010

I found a great post on how to see if a user is part of a single group in SharePoint 2010; SP 2013 has improved and changed a bit.  Here is the original link: http://styledpoint.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-check-to-see-if-user-exists-in-a-group-via-javascript-ecma/

I've modified this because our use case requires defining if a user is a member of one of several groups to show or hide a section of html.  The problem is that I can't concat the userGroups collection that contains the user to see if the user is part of more than one group.  If I don't merge the user collection, then the function returns true/false for every group included.  Any thoughts?

```
//http://styledpoint.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-check-to-see-if-user-exists-in-a-group-via-javascript-ecma/
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfAnyListedGroup(strGroupName, functionComplete2) {
    //Setup Vars
    currentContext = null;
    currentWeb = null;
    allGroups = null;
    leaderGroup = null;
    currentUser = null;
    groupUsers = null;
    //Get an instance of the Client Content.
    currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //Grab the client web object.
    currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();
    //Get the current user object
    currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    currentContext.load(currentUser);
    //Setup the groupColletion.
    allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);
    //currentContext.load(allGroups, 'Include(Title, Id, Users.Include(Title, LoginName))');


    //Now populate the objects above.
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, GetAllGroupsExecuteOnSuccess2),Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnFailure2));

    // GroupCollection - Load - SUCCESS
    function GetAllGroupsExecuteOnSuccess2(sender, args) {
        // CHECK THE GROUPS
        // Time to Enumerate through the group collection that was returned.
        var groupEnumerator = allGroups.getEnumerator();
        var groupexists = false;
        var groupUsers = null;
        // Loop for the collection.
        while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            //Grab the Group Item.
            var group = groupEnumerator.get_current();

            //Since you are enumerating through out the group names, theoretically you should be able to list multiple groups like editors and admins
            //Separate the group name into an array so that multiple groups could be used
            //alert(strGroupName);          

            var myarray = strGroupName.split(',');

            for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
            {

               //console.log(myarray[i]);
                if (group.get_title().indexOf(myarray[i]) > -1) { //if (group.get_title().indexOf(strGroupName) > -1) {
                    //console.log("'"+myarray[i]+"'");
                    groupexists = true;
                    // Now that we have the group let's grab the list of users.
                    if (groupUsers == null) {
                        groupUsers = group.get_users();         
                    } else {
                        //groupUsers = groupUsers.addUser(group.get_users());                           
                        //groupUsers = groupUsers.concat(group.get_users());                        
                        //groupUsers = groupUsers.Concat(group.get_users());                        
                        groupUsers = groupUsers.merge(group.get_users());                       
                    }

                    //console.log(group.get_users());
                    break;
                }
            }
            /*if (group.get_title().indexOf(strGroupName) > -1) {
            // Now that we have the group let's grab the list of users.
            groupUsers = group.get_users();
            currentContext.load(groupUsers);
            currentContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, SingleGroupExecuteOnSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnFailure));
            }*/
        }
        //console.log(groupexists);
        if (groupexists == false) {
            //Run the delegate function and return false because there was no match for the group name.
            functionComplete2(false);
        }       
            //After iterating through the provided groups, then call the success function 
            //User could be listed more than once, but you need it to show up only once
            currentContext.load(groupUsers);
            currentContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, SingleGroupExecuteOnSuccess2),Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnFailure2));
    }

    // Single Group - Load - SUCCESS
    function SingleGroupExecuteOnSuccess2(sender, args) {
        alert('SingleGroupExeSuc2');
        // Time to setup the Enumerator
        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        // This is the flag to set to true if the user is in the group.
        var boolUserInGroup = false;
        // and start looping.
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            //Grab the User Item.
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            // and finally. If a Group User ID Matches the current user ID then they are in the group!
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                console.log(groupUser.get_id());
                boolUserInGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //Run the delegate function with the bool;
        functionComplete2(boolUserInGroup);
    }

    // GroupCollection or Single Group - Load - FAILURE
    function ExecuteOnFailure2(sender, args) {
        //Run the delegate function and return false because there was no match.
        alert('failed');
        functionComplete2(false);
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the function:

```
IsCurrentUserMemberOfAnyListedGroup("Admin,Member", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {    
                    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)    {
                        alert('Show');       // The current user is in the group! Hurrah!    
                    } else {
                        alert('Dont Show');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made it too complecated .. 
why don't you simply get all user Groups (e.g. using this solution: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetGroupCollectionFromUser&referringTitle=Users%20and%20Groups) as a string and for each Grop Name you have to search just get an index in the string ... if it is -1 at least once - return false and break..

Hope it helps,
Andrey.
(can paste a code example later, if needed.. don't have access right now)

Comment: Currently I'm using only the single group.  When I need more complicated I'm using SPServices.  I'm hoping that someone can make a suggestion that I can post a full answer for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have meant: (checked it works as you described - verifies if the user is in several groups .. you can put all you groups for verification into array and check them in loop... I just simplified it for my example.)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    getAllUserGroups();

    var groupToCheck1 = "PMO";
    var groupToCheck2 = "HR22";
    if (!checkUserGroups(groupToCheck1) || !checkUserGroups(groupToCheck2)) {
        //  do your job
        alert("User do not exist in both " + groupToCheck1 + " and " + groupToCheck2 + " groups");
    }
});

//simple verification
function checkUserGroups(groupName) {
    if (window.AllUserGroups.indexOf(groupName) == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//get and store all groups in the global var.
function getAllUserGroups() {
    window.AllUserGroups = "";
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
        userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
        async: false,
        completefunc: function (xData) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Group").each(function () {
                var groupName = $(this).attr("Name");
                window.AllUserGroups += groupName + ";";
            });
        }
    });
}
```